# How to apply bevel to intersecting edges of a geometry nodes based Difference Boolean

Tags: geometry-nodes, bevel

I am trying to have a non destructive bevel on intersecting edges of an object after a difference boolean. I have found that in 3.3. the Mesh Boolean node now has a new attribute called "Intersecting Edges" which sounds like a reference to the, well, intersecting edges of the boolean. But I have found no way of applying the Boolean to this edges. Here is a very basic reproduction of what I am taking about.

[image: Geometry Nodes]

One way I have thought is to somehow create a vertex group out of the intersecting edges and then run a Bevel on that Vertex Group.

[image: Modifier List]

Is there any way to do something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to apply the bevel modifier to a vertex group is absolutely correct.

However, the vertex group must be created first, and then you can add the *Intersecting Edges* to it in *Geometry Nodes* via the node `Store Named Attribute`:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>